# K6 test execution behavior

Tags: typescript, performance-testing, k6

Hello everyone.
I am new to K6 and have a question regarding test execution.
For example i have some small test with given config.

```
export const options = {
stages: [
    { target: 10, duration: '30s'}
]}
```

when i run test with this config, at the bottom of a console i can see  this line 
[======================================] 01/10 VUs.
Does it mean that k6 executes tests sequentially and only after one iteration is done next one starts?
I thought that the test will be executed simultaniously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`options.stages` is a shorthand for a single scenario with a [ramping VUs](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/scenarios/executors/ramping-vus/) executor.

With your stages, k6 will start with a single VU at second 0 of your test and then increase the number of VUs linearly over time so that it reaches 10 concurrent VUs after 30 seconds. After 30 seconds, your test will end.

Comment: Thanks for a clarification